# Azure storage blob to Azure Event Hub

Tags: c#, .net, azure

How to transfer CSV file data from Azure storage blob to Azure Event Hub?
I tried with Azure function. But I didn't got result.

Comment: Please edit your question and include some code. Also tell us details about any error you're getting.

Comment: @GauravMantri Mantri I don't' have exact idea about it. do you have any specific architecture for that please explain to me.

Comment: Rushik...Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately things don't work this way here. People will help you provided you have done some work. Simply asking for things without trying anything is not going to work. You mentioned above that you tried with Azure Function. What have you tried there? That would be a good starting point. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried with Azure function trigger method based on this following links :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob

Comment: Based on my understanding, if you want to use Azure function, you could create a Httptrigger function  with [eventhub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output---example) as output. In the Httptrigger function, you could add you logic to read azure storage blob.

Comment: @Tom Sun Can you provide some example links?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function is proper solution for your task.

As input use AzureBlob trigger, as function output use Azure EventHub, but in the middle you must write some code to transform your blob (csv file) to EventHub message.

Hence you didn't add any code, I can't help more.

Comment: Till now I just created sample example as per below link.

for input I used this example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input

for output I used this example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output---c-example

can you give me idea of which type of code i need to write for middle layer??

Comment: For the start - as input parameter you have `streamBlob` so basically you need read stream line by line and parse your csv string. Look at this blog post: https://danashurst.com/parsing-a-csv-file/

After that you need write your result to event hub like in your link

Comment: Or if you don't want do anything with your csv data, you can take `streamBlob` and literally send it to event hub without parsing, if you want, you can use `streamReader.ReadToEnd` method to convert it to raw string and you have output parameter  `outputEventHubMessage` where you can pass this string